# How to execute a function only after another one is finished on browser Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a web app chess game, so every piece will have an event listener to wait until a player clicks on it. When a player clicks on a piece (for now I'm only working with pawns) it's id will be saved and printed out, and only after this all squares should wait for a click (I'm not working with valid squares, can be any square); and if a square is clicked, it's id should be saved and printed out.

But on console, when I click a pawn, it's id is printed twice, one time for the normal print, but another time for the square print (So it took square's print). So instead of the programm to wait to call the function that prints the square id after clicking the piece, the programm prints the piece id in the place of the square id. So I think the programm is not waiting until the first function is finished:

```js
//Each div(square) of chess board

var $class_white = [...document.querySelectorAll('.house_white')];
var $class_black = [...document.querySelectorAll('.house_black')];

//Every pawn

var $class_pawn = [...document.querySelectorAll('.pawn')];

//Variables to store the piece and square id.
var $piece;
var $square;


//Every pawn is waiting to be clicked
function $$wait_pawns(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', $$pawn_clicked);
}

//This will add the event listener type 'click' to the squares
function $$prepare_squares(){
    $class_white.forEach($$wait_squares);
    $class_black.forEach($$wait_squares);
}

//If a pawn is clicked, it will save the pawn id and then call $$prepare_squares() to add an event listener type 'click' to the squares
function $$pawn_clicked(event) {
    $piece = event.target.id;
    console.log($piece);
    $$prepare_squares();
}

//Now every square is wainting to be clicked
function $$wait_squares(item){
    item.addEventListener('click', $$square_clicked);
}

//After a square is clicked, it's id will be saved and will be printed.
function $$square_clicked(event2){
    $square = event2.target.id;
    console.log($square);
}

//This will add an event listener type 'click' to all pawns
$class_pawn.forEach($$wait_pawns);
```

[This is an screenshot of the console and chess board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9g4V.jpg)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    /*background-color: rgb(0,0,80);*/
    background-image: url("black.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.pawn{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}

.bishop{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}

.rock{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}

.horse{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}

#king{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}


#queen{
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    /*border-bottom: 9px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    border-left: 9px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    border-top: 9px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    border-right: 9px solid rgb(0,0,0);*/
}

.house_white {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.house_black {
    display: flex;
    background: rgb(0,100,0);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#demo {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    height:50px;
    width:220px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 90%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif, serif;
    font-size: 1.30rem;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(200,200,200);
}

#start {
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 90%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif, serif;
    font-size: 1.30rem;
    outline: none;
}
#start:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
#circle {
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
}

#queen {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
}

/*#joke {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 15%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 6px solid;
    border-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Dynamic, light, fast and simple">
        <meta name="author" content="necromancerc-137">
        <meta name="keywords" content="dynamic">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Javascript testing</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <main>
            <!--<img id="joke" src="joke.gif">-->
            <div id="demo">Frontend...</div>
            <button id="start">Help!</button>
            <div class="container">
                <div id = "a8" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "b8" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "c8" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "d8" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "e8" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "f8" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "g8" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "h8" class="house_black"></div>

                <div id = "a7" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "b7" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "c7" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "d7" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "e7" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "f7" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "g7" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "h7" class="house_white"></div>

                <div id = "a6" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "b6" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "c6" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "d6" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "e6" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "f6" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "g6" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "h6" class="house_black"></div>

                <div id = "a5" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "b5" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "c5" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "d5" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "e5" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "f5" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "g5" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "h5" class="house_white"></div>

                <div id = "a4" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "b4" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "c4" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "d4" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "e4" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "f4" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "g4" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "h4" class="house_black"></div>

                <div id = "a3" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "b3" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "c3" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "d3" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "e3" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "f3" class="house_white"></div>
                <div id = "g3" class="house_black"></div>
                <div id = "h3" class="house_white"></div>

                <div id = "a2" class="house_white"><img id="pawn0" class="pawn" src="pawn.png"></div>
                <div id = "b2" class="house_black"><img id="pawn1" class="pawn" src="pawn.png"></div>
                <div id = "c2" class="house_white"><img id="pawn2" class="pawn" src="pawn.png"></div>
                <div id = "d2" class="house_black"><img id="pawn3" class="pawn" src="pawn.png"></div>
                <div id = "e2" class="house_white"><img id="pawn4" class="pawn" src="pawn.png"></div>
                <div id = "f2" class="house_black"><img id="pawn5" class="pawn" src="pawn.png"></div>
                <div id = "g2" class="house_white"><img id="pawn6" class="pawn" src="pawn.png"></div>
                <div id = "h2" class="house_black"><img id="pawn7" class="pawn" src="pawn.png"></div>

                <div id = "a1" class="house_black"><img class="rock" src="rock.png"></div>
                <div id = "b1" class="house_white"><img class="horse" src="horse.png"></div>
                <div id = "c1" class="house_black"><img class="bishop" src="bishop.png"></div>
                <div id = "d1" class="house_white"><img id="queen" src="queen.png"></div>
                <div id = "e1" class="house_black"><img id="king" src="king.png"></div>
                <div id = "f1" class="house_white"><img class="bishop" src="bishop.png"></div>
                <div id = "g1" class="house_black"><img class="horse" src="horse.png"></div>
                <div id = "h1" class="house_white"><img class="rock" src="rock.png"></div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I think the programm is not waiting until the first function is finished

That's not what's happening. A non-`async` JavaScript function **always** runs to completion (unless the entire environment is terminated, like closing a web page).

The click event *propagates* ("bubbles") from child elements to their parent element to *its* parent element, etc. Since your pawns are child elements of the squares, after handling the click event on the pawn, the click event bubbles to the square and gets handled there.

There are a couple of things you'll need to do:

1. Prevent the event from bubbling by using [`event.stopPropagation();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on the `event` object in `$$pawn_clicked`
2. Have variables storing state information for your program so it knows whether it's expecting to get a click on a square. I think that you already have that in the `$piece` variable. So your click handler for squares should only do something when `$piece` is not the "no piece" value (looks like you're using `undefined` for that).

Comment: @irtexas also to add to this answer a little. You need to dispose of your square listeners when not in use ( in this specific case, might be better to add a css property of `pointer-events: 'none'` ) than looping through the squares everytime you click a pawn.. keep in mind that event listeners stack.

Comment: It worked! 2 days of struggling... Thank you very much.

Comment: @zergski I didn't understand what should I do.

Comment: @T.J Crowder what does it mean: "The click event propagates ("bubbles") from child elements to their parent element to its parent element, etc". And how the pawns are child elements?

Comment: @irtexas19 - When you write `<div id = "a2" class="house_white"><img id="pawn0" class="pawn" src="pawn.png"></div>` in HTML and load it in the browser, that creates a `div` element containing an `img` element as a child (it's inside the `div`). Regarding bubbling, [this diagram](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) in the DOM events specification is really useful for understanding the three phases of event dispatch: capture (goes from the document to the target through each of its parents), target (at the target), and bubbling (working back from the target to the document).